# Android Custom Keyboard: How do I add the functionality of a list of items(ex. Emoticons)?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have a working custom keyboard(as a service):

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {
```

It works but what I am trying to do is add a way to show a (scrollable) list of items for the user to select and by selecting it, it will type that. For example, (by using pressing another tab or a button), a different keyboard layout/mode will show up and it will show a list of emojis to choose from, except I am not trying to do it with emojis but quotes and ascii faces.

Answer (score 0):

Create another keyboard and switch keyboard on the onKeyPress, like this:

```
keyboardView.setKeyboard(anotherKeyboard);
```

You can do this for many different keyboards, just set the keyboard that you want when the code of the key you want comes.

```
public final static int NUMERIC_KEYBOARD = -16;
public final static int DEFAULT_KEYBOARD = -17;
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {    
switch(primaryCode){
        case NUMERIC_KEYBOARD:
        kv.setKeyboard( numericKeyboard );
    break;
    case DEFAULT_KEYBOARD:
        kv.setKeyboard( keyboard );
```

and on your keyboard's xml:

```
 <Key android:codes="-16"   android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_symbol" android:keyWidth="18.7%p"/>
```